# How to add a fixed header using KeyboardAwareScrollView in react-native

Tags: react-native

Below is my code, in this code, the Navigation bar is not fixed when
the keyboard scrolls up.Whenever i tap the last textInput, the keyboard pops up and the navigation bar is not fixed. Please help me in fixing the 
navigation bar.

```
 <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#f6f6f6'}}>
    <View style={{height: 44}}>
      <Text style={{fontSize: 16, marginTop: 20}}>
        NavigationBar
      </Text>
    </View>
    <KeyboardAwareScrollView
       automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
       keyboardShouldPersistTaps='always'
       scrollEventThrottle={10}
       extraHeight={250}
       resetScrollToCoords={{x: 0, y: 0}}
    >
      <View>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 16}}>
          Header
        </Text>
      </View>
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />

    </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
  </View>
```